# How to create a class to handle multidimensional arraylist

Tags: java

During my search for info about multidimensional arraylist, I read that you could create a class to handle the multidimensional arraylist.

I'm doing a Android game similar to Bejeweled, and instead of using a common multidimensional grid, I guess this would be better!? I also has a list of all the sprite objects and I wonder if I can store and control all this objects with a multidimensional arraylist class?

But I'm not sure how a class would look like and how do I set and get values from the arraylists? Is there anyone who are interested to explain how it's working and show a simple code example? Thanks!

EDIT: I want to have objects in the arraylists like this example `int grid[][] = new int[8][8];` but instead of integers, I want to have objects. And I wonder if it's possible to get and set values the same easy was like in the example I just showed?

EDIT 2: I have a grid 8x8 and that's why I'm using a array like [8][8], but I can only have values of type integers or booleans at each positions. I also have to use an arraylist to handle all the 64 objects that has a positions within this grid. Each object store it's position, both in the grid array and the position on the screen. I just wanted to make it a little bit simplier to handle and create a gird with multidimensional arrayList to both store the objects and have a grid? Possible or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "multidimensional arraylist" ?

Comment: Like this int grid[][] = new int[8][8]; but with arrayLists

Comment: You could use an `ArrayList<Arraylist>`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but how do I get and set info to the objects methods and fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no big difference between ArrayList and array.

Would say there are only 2 pros of ArrayList:

- ability to dynamically change a size
- adding new element at end of array, without need to look for first empty slot

And for multidimensional another pros is possibility to have different lengths for nested ArrayLists.

In Your case I think You don't need any of this so choose one You feel more comfortable, If You don't know how to make ArrayList of ArrayLists but know how to use array use them.

But just to answer Your question.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> root = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

root.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
root.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
root.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
root.add(new ArrayList<Object>());

root.get(1).set(1, Object); //puts new object at position 1,1

Object o = root.get(1).get(1); //gets object from position 1,1
```

With multidimensional array:

```
Object[][] grid = new Object[8][8];

grid[1][4] = new Object(); //set new object at position 1,4

grid[1][4].doSmth(); //calls method doSmth() of object stored at position 1,4

Object o = grid[1][4]; //gets object at position 1,4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For this game I have a grid 8x8, and that's why I used a array like [8][8], but I can only have boolean or integers values in this, so I also have to have an arraylist to hold all of the 64 objects in the grid. In each grid I have to position in the grid array stored, I hope you understand what what I'm trying to explain!? I thought I could create a multidimensional array like a grid of 8x8 with my objects?? Is this possible?

Comment: You may create array of any type You like. You are not limited to primitive types `Object[][] grid = new Object[8][8];` gives You multidimensional array of objects.

Comment: Aha, that looks interesting....but...I'm a little bit confused how I should continue....Can I get and set values to fields and methods then by just call it's positions, like [1][3]...? Can you give me a short example?

Comment: Really nice! I'm testing and rewriting my code right now to see if it's working the way I want. I guess this makes it much easier to handle the objects and the game!?

Comment: matter of preferences, I would choose arrays in this case.

Comment: Can I remove an object at a position and add a new object at that position?

Comment: when You put object into array, the old one is removed. If You wish just to remove and leave empty set it to null

Answer (score 2):

```
    int size =8;
    List<List<Integer>> list  = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(size);

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) 
        {
            Integer x = list.get(0).get(1); //access the 0,1 element
        }
    }
```

**EDIT :**
If you want to use a specific class. For ex: `Node`, you could use `List<List<Node>>` instead of `List<List<Integer>>` and then access it. You can then call any methods of the `Node` class as follows:

```
 Node node = list.get(0).get(1); // access the Node at 0,1
 node.getProperties();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my array in the comment above was just an example. I want to handle objects in the arrays, not integers

Comment: @3D-kreativ then replace the `Integer` in the above code with another class like `List<List<YourClass>>`

Comment: OK, but I would like to know how I get and set values to this class and it's arraylists?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<Integer>> multiList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
multiList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
Integer element = multi.get(0).get(0); // element at 0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

First your start with defining your multi-dimensional arrayList

```
int size = 8;
List<List<YourClass>> 2dList = new ArrayList<List<YourClass>>(size);
```

then you initialize it

```
for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < size; rowIndex++) {
    List<YourClass> row = new ArrayList<YourClass>(size)

    for(int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < size; columnIndex++) {
        row.add(new YourClass());
    }

    2dList.add(row);
}
```

now you have an `size`x`size` ArrayList with instances of your class

to access it:

```
2dList.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex) // will return the YourClass-Object you placed there
```

if you want to replace the object on a certain position with another instance you need to remove the old object first:

```
2dList.get(rowIndex).remove(columnIndex);
2dList.get(rowIndex).add(columnIndex, newYourClass);
```